# How to make up for changed Sql Server database password

Tags: .net, asp.net, sql-server, database

There is a website made using .net, the maker has gone and we can't find him.
For a long time we don't know the password of the sql server database, today I tried to reset the password and then found the website can't connect to the database!
However I've got the .cs and .aspx and .dll files, I checked the code and find it getting connection in the following way:

```
    public string ConnectString
{
    get
    {
        if (this.connectString == string.Empty)
        {
            System.Configuration.AppSettingsReader Reader = new AppSettingsReader();
            connectString = (string)Reader.GetValue("conn", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
        }
        return connectString;
    }
    set
    {
        connectString = value;
    }
}

public SqlConnection SqlConnection
{
    get
    {
        if (SqlCn == null)
        {
           SqlCn = new SqlConnection(ConnectString);

        }
        return SqlCn;
    }
}
```

Since I've only known some JDBC and never touched .net, i've no ider how this works:

```
System.Configuration.AppSettingsReader Reader = new AppSettingsReader();
 connectString = (string)Reader.GetValue("conn", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
```

Can I find the connectString in some file so I can change the password back? I searched all the files I have and can't find any containing the keyword "pwd" or "database" is useful. Now I have a new database password, can I simply change the line:

```
SqlCn = new SqlConnection("server=127.0.0.1;database=****;uid=sa;pwd=****");
```

Still I want to know how to recompile the .cs to .aspx, and what I need to know to recover the website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for the configuration file.  App.config is my guess.

Comment: My GOD..I found it!Now it works! thank you so much. I've been doing this all the morning..

Answer (score 0):

Find the webapp's web.config file, and look to the `<appSettings>` section, `<conn>` property.

Answer (score 0):

from what you are asking, you definitely are not a techie. you would have to look at your web.config (as you have mentioned aspx) for "Initial Catalog" under "conn" key in `<appSettings>` section. Your server cannot be 127.0.0.1 unless you are running your web server (IIS) and your SQL Server from the same machine. I would suggest you hire someone who has some programming experience if you are looking for a long term solution including maintenance of your application

Edit:If you do have access to your SQL Server/if you have a DBA, you can reset the password for this user and use the new  password. Rather than using SQL Authentication (username/password), I would suggest you to use Windows authentication as it is more secure

Comment: Yes I majored in Java,not any familiar to these..This must be an easy question,so I just chosed the first answer..